# Is there a way of automating a process of receiving PDFs and entering details in MS Dynamics?

Tags: automation, ocr, microsoft-dynamics

My organisation receives a number of referral forms which come through as PDF attachments (one attachment/referral per email and approximately 1000 emails per month). Currently, we have an admin who is opening up the PDFs and copying the data into Dynamics which seems quite a laborious job.

Is there a cheap/preferably free way (we're a non-profit organisation but imagine most would want to pay as little as possible!) of doing this? Any/all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.